# Bluetooth output with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord session category doesn't work

Tags: ipad, audio, bluetooth

Anyone have any idea why I can't get bluetooth output to work on an iPad (iOS 5) under the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category.

Below is the code I'm using to setup the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category and enable bluetooth.  If I switch the category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, bluetooth output works just fine to a variety of headsets and headphones. As soon as I switch to PlayAndRecord, no bluetooth output.

What am I doing wrong?

Suggestions, hypotheses appreciated.  Thanks.

```
- (BOOL) setAudioSessionCategoryToPlayAndRecordWithBluetoothEnabled {
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err;

    if (![audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err])
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"oh no...");
        return NO;
    }

        // make active
    [audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];

        // allow bluetooth
    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
    OSStatus stat =  AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                              kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                                              sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                                              &allowBluetoothInput
                                              );

    if (stat) {
        fprintf(stderr,"not good...");
        return FALSE;
    }


        // check for bluetooth route 
        // (NB: this never works if category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;
    stat = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &route);
    NSLog(@"route = %@", route);    


    return TRUE;

}
```